# Unable to open worksheet in excel with Listbox selection

Tags: vba, excel

[Code Page 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s14LG.png)[Code Page 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/os3WZ.png)I am trying to open the sheet with listbox selection. The code is as under. But it is showing an error. I am new to vba. Plz help

```
Public Sub AddData_Click()
Dim iRow As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim Sht As String
Sht.Text = ListBox1.SelectedItem.Tostring()
Worksheets(CStr(Sht)).Activate
```

Comment: show more _environment_ of your code (like a Userform screenshot), and confirm you are on VBA and not on VB-Net

Comment: My userform contains a list box and other boxes to enter data. I pressed Alt+F11 on excel and I am working on that window.

Comment: Error is compiler error and Method or Data Member not found. The error colors the Public Sub AddData_Click() on yellow and .SelectedItem is selected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
Private Sub AddData_Click()
Dim i As Integer
Dim sht As String
For i = 0 To ListBox1.ListCount - 1
    If ListBox1.Selected(i) Then
        sht = ListBox1.List(i)
    End If
Next i
If sht = "" Then
    MsgBox "You didn't select an item in the listbox.", vbExclamation
    Exit Sub
Else
    Worksheets(sht).Activate
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Is MultiSelect property of the ListBox1 set to false? i.e. it shouldn't allow multiple select.

Comment: Multiselect is set to 0 - fmMultiselectSingle

Comment: Then it should work. Also assuming it's a single column ListBox.i.e. ColumnCount is set to 1. What exactly your ListBox1 contains, sheet names?

Comment: It contains sheet names such as ASDF_123

Comment: And the sheetname is a combination of 2 strings which I input from the user. There are no problems in the sheet creation and sheet listing in the listbox.

Comment: ColumnCount is set to 1

Comment: Are you sure when AddData control is clicked, an item in the ListBox1 is selected? Try inserting a break point and use debug.print ListBox1.value to see what you get?

Comment: ListBox1.value seems to have a Null Value as when the error comes and I hover my mouse over, it says so.

Comment: When I click add data, it is supposed to add some data into the sheet which is selected in the listbox. It is not doing so and giving a type mismatch error.

Comment: I have edited the answer, see if that works for you now.

Comment: It shows the error message "You didn't select an item in the listbox."

Comment: I have added the view of the form

Comment: Please suggest if combo box would be better

Comment: What is the label for ListBox1 on the UserForm? Is it Part No? It doesn't matter what control you choose whether ListBox or ComboBox, matter is how and when an item is selected in the listbox before clicking the AddData button.

Comment: It is ListBox1.

Comment: I am unable to post the whole code because it says too much code.

Comment: By Label I meant label shown on the UserForm next to the controls. The logic is pretty simple. In a blank workbook, insert a UserForm with a ListBox control called ListBox1 and a command button called AddData, populate the ListBox1 with the Sheet names and place the suggested code underneath the command button AddData and check the code. That will give you an idea about how the code works. Something wrong is being happend due to your other code, maybe somehow ListBox1 is being cleared when AddData button is clicked.

Comment: I have added a demo version on Dropbox, you may view the file to know how the proposed code works. https://www.dropbox.com/s/okrdo9h5p4p71at/Update%20Stats%20Database%20v1.3.xlsm?dl=0

Comment: I am unable to understand how your sample code relates to my problem

Comment: Got it buddy... after I did as you said, I found out that I was not selecting the listbox selection at all... I was just using the Up and Down Arrows to display the sheet but not selecting them. When I created a form with sheet names and listBoxes, then I found out what wrong I was doing. Thank you very much for your help...

Comment: Great! Glad your issue is resolved at last. :) Please take a moment to accept the answer to mark your question as solved. :)

Answer (score 0):

you could try this:

```
Private Sub AddData_Click()    
    With Me.ListBox1
        If .ListIndex = -1 Then
            MsgBox "No item selected!"
        Else
            Worksheets(.Value).Activate
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: It is saying No Item Selected. I am just viewing selecting the list box values and not pressing any button.

Comment: What is "AddData"? then name of a `Listbox` or of a `Button` object?

Comment: AddData is the name of the form

Comment: why would you want to react at the user clicking on the userform instead of on a button or a listbox? please edit your question adding as many details as necessary to reproduce your environment and needs

Comment: Please suggest if combo box would be better

Comment: I'm not in the position of suggesting anything till I get the whole picture!

Comment: I am unable to enter the code. It says too much code and need more details.

Comment: But it shows error.. The value of Sht is Blank("") and hence error pops up saying Type MisMatch